# Rear wheel stuck after taking off nuts on axle

Tags: wheels

As in the title. I was trying to do some repairs after my derailer snapped and damaged the bike. When taking the rear wheel off (to get to the fender) the wheel got stuck in place after taking the lugs off one side.

The other lug is too tight to remove, (using my wrench is stripping the nut) Does anyone know of any fixes?

Comment: Photos of your bike and the rear wheel and especially the axle/hub/derailleur area would help us understand what's going on. For example, I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to as "lugs".

Comment: Sounds like the previous assembler used an impact wrench and overtightened things, or you're undoing something that doesn't need to be undone.  Please add photos with [edit] or link them somehow.

Comment: @Armand Probably referring to “lug nuts”, like you’d find on a car.

Comment: @Armand Unfortunately I do not own a camera or smartphone. So pics are out of the question. I think I figured out why it's stuck then, seems like the axle shifted a bit when I let the first nut off and it got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing bolt-on wheels, it’s best to only slightly loosen each nut at a time. You don’t want to completely remove each side in one go, because then you get your current situation, where the other side refuses to come off. You end up spinning the entire wheel along with the nut, so it won’t unscrew. Loosen the left side an quarter turn, then the right side a quarter turn, then the left side again...and so forth. I would do up the nuts tight again and start over. Perhaps begin by breaking loose the other nut so you’re sure it’s not corroded in place or something.

You might want to consider using a proper 15mm wrench. I presume you’re using an adjustable wrench, which isn’t very precise and can strip nuts and bolts (as you’ve discovered) if even slightly too loose at high torques. Basic wrenches are available at hardware and automotive stores for like 10 dollars, so it’s a worthwhile investment. For a couple extra dollars you can upgrade to a ratcheting wrench which will make the job slightly faster.

Comment: If it's that stuck, a bit of penetrating oil carefully applied to the axle where the nut meets it might help.

Comment: Thanks Maple! I'm gonna head to the hardware store later today and follow up on your advice. 

You're the best, Thank you!

Comment: @Nicholas Martin You’re very welcome!

Comment: @MaplePanda Just wanted to let you know your advice worked! Bike is up and running again thanks to you! Thank you!

Comment: @Nicholas Martin Awesome! Glad to help, that’s why I’m on this site. Enjoy the bike!